# How to set a fixed or minimum tick limit in a chart with chart.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I have a chart, using `chart.js`, and I see there is an option `maxTicksLimit`, but that isn't enough, because my data on the `X-Axis` can range between 5 (so in this case I would need 5 ticks at 1 stepSize) but can go as high as 320, in this case I would need 5 or 8 ticks with 20 or 25 stepSize.

Is there a way to define a minimum amount of ticks? The ideal for me would be:

```
minimum amount of ticks = 4
maximum amount of ticks = 8
```

Because if I put `maxTicksLimit: 5`, on higher numbers they will be 5, but if my X-axis range is 0-25, I'll only have 4 ticks for some reason (0-10, 10-15, 15-20, 20-25)

As my X-axis range is dinamically changed based on inputs,
The best solution would be to have something like this:

When the `xAxes` range is:

```
0-5 -> 5 ticks with step 1

0-10 -> 5 ticks with step 2

0-15 -> 5 ticks with step 3

from 15 to 40, up to 8 ticks with step 5

from 40 to 80, up to 8 ticks with step 10

from 80 to 160, up to 8 ticks with step 20

from 160 to 240, up to 8 ticks with step 30

from 240 to 320, up to 8 ticks with step 40
```

is this possible?

Comment: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2539